# Link and Div Scripts running simultaneously HTML/JSF/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project, that requires me to have a div, which will contain some items to edit, and another div, which is not shown at all times. The code looks as follows:

```
<div id="div1">
    <h:outputText value="Fixed Div" />
    <h:outputLink id="openDiv">Open Div</h:outputLink>
    <div id="currentlyUnused">TODO</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <h:outputText value="Other Div" />
    <div id="currentlyUnused2">TODO</div>
</div>
```

Some additional CSS for both divs:

```
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
```

Also add for `div2`:

```
z-index: 10;
display: none;
```

So, what I am attempting is to open `div2` when the link in `div1` is clicked. I have had this happening by using JQuery scripts. The scripts look as follows:

```
<script>
    $("#openDiv").click(function() {
        $("#div2").show( "slow" );
        $("#div1").animate({
            'marginLeft' : "-=30px"
        });
        $("#div1").animate({
            'marginTop' : "-=20px"
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $("#div1").click(function() {
        $("#div2").hide( "slow" );
        $("#div1").animate({
            'marginLeft' : "+=30px"
        });
        $("#div1").animate({
            'marginTop' : "+=20px"
        });
    });
</script>
```

The one to close `div2` is similar, except that `div2` will close when `div1` (which is sticking out on the side) is clicked. They have borders around so I can see exactly how they move etc, however it's only styling related, as well as z-index on `div2` (to make it overlap etc)

On to the problem at hand though. Since the divs are animated, I notice the movement on the screen, and I know how I want the divs to move. When `div2` pops up in the middle of the screen, `div1` will move 20px up, and 30px left. When `div2` closes, `div1` will move 20px down, and 30px right (to it's original position)

I have noticed that when I click the link to open `div2`, the following steps happen:

1. `div1` moves 30px left
2. `div1` moves 20px up
3. `div2` opens briefly
4. `div2` closes
5. `div1` moves 30px right
6. `div1` moves 20px down

This has led me to believe that both the scripts are running when the link is clicked. The only possible reason I can think of, is that the click scripts - both on the link and on the div are triggering at the same time.

I've been sitting and trying different combinations as to how I can handle this. I have also tried making use of `pointer-events` to try and resolve the problem, but to no avail thus far.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the button is in the form and both have a jquery oncklick.
query preseves the click on the button as a click on div1 aswel.

To fix this use (event.stoppropagation): https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

```
<script>
    $("#openDiv").click(function( event ) {
        //Prevent click flowing into div1
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#div2").show( "slow" );
        $("#div1").animate({
            'marginLeft' : "-=30px"
        });
        $("#div1").animate({
            'marginTop' : "-=20px"
        });
    });
</script>
```